# Bulk renaming files from CSV using more than one column to verify file name

Tags: powershell

I have a DB dump of attachments with DB name and a CSV file with three columns.  First column is DB_name, second column is original name, third is file size in KB.

I can get PowerShell to use first column to rename to second column but cannot get to also use third column to make sure the correct file gets renamed.  Second column has duplicate original names and I need to confirm that the correct file get renamed by size.

Example CSV content:

```
ID,Name,Size
00P3400000cd7rsEAA,201516003_8D_FINAL.doc,4236288
```

```
Import-Csv test.csv | ForEach-Object{
    Rename-Item $_.ID $_.Name
}
```

Comment: Something along the line: `if((Get-Item $_.ID).Size / 1kb) -eq $_.'Size in KB'){Rename-Item $_.ID $_.Name}`

Comment: No, the foreach is necessary, my line was intended to replace your `Rename-Item`. Don't post longer code snippets into comments, edit your question. And provide a (sanitized) sample of your csv data.

Comment: **PLEASE** [edit] your question to contain additional information and format it properly.